# WSO2 ESB populating JMS message store config issue

Tags: java, wso2, wso2-esb

I am trying to populate a JMS message store from the WSO2 ESB.

I set up the following configuration for the message store...

```
<messageStore name="JMSMS" class="org.apache.synapse.message.store.impl.jms.JmsStore" 
xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <parameter name="java.naming.factory.initial">org.wso2.andes.jndi.PropertiesFileInitialContextFactory
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="java.naming.provider.url">repository/conf/jndi.properties</parameter>
    <parameter name="store.jms.destination">JMSMS</parameter>
    <parameter name="store.jms.username">admin</parameter>
    <parameter name="store.jms.password">admin</parameter>
    <parameter name="store.jms.JMSSpecVersion">1.1</parameter>
```

When I start the ESB I get the following error :-

> [2014-07-29 16:43:45,633] ERROR - JmsStore Store [JMSMS]. Could not
>   create a new connection to the broker. Initial Context
>   Factory:[org.apache.qpid.jn di.PropertiesFileInitialContextFactory];
>   Provider URL:[repository/conf/jndi.properties]; Connection
>   Factory:[null].

I have used the above `java.naming.factory.initial` to successfully connect to a standard Message Broker queue as an endpoint without going through the Message store.

I have also tried changing the value of `java.naming.factory.initial` to `org.apache.qpid.jndi.PropertiesFileInitialContextFactory` but get the same error.

Does anyone have an idea of what config or files I am missing?

Cheers
Macca

**Update**

Below is the jndi.properties and axis2.xml config I am using

JNDI.Properties

```
connectionfactory.ConnectionFactory = amqp://admin:admin@clientID/carbon?brokerlist='tcp://inf02-3:5673'

queue.JMSMS=JMSMS
```

axis2.xml

```
<transportSender name="jms" class="org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSSender"> 
    <parameter name="default" locked="false"> 
        <parameter name="java.naming.factory.initial" locked="false">org.wso2.andes.jndi.PropertiesFileInitialContextFactory</parameter> 
        <parameter name="java.naming.provider.url" locked="false">repository/conf/jndi.properties</parameter> 
        <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName" locked="false">ConnectionFactory</parameter> 
    </parameter> 
</transportSender>
```

Comment: There are a few configuration files you need to update.  Looks like you want to use the WSO2 Message Broker.  Have you set that up correctly. (https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB480/Configure+with+WSO2+Message+Broker) Good article to follow.  Also it would be good to see the contents of the jndi.properties file

Comment: Yes. I used that so I could connect to the queue I mentioned in the article. That worked. It seems to be an issue around the java.naming.factory.initial parameter.

Comment: Added jndi.properties file I am using

Answer (score 2):

Reason for the error that you are getting "Connection Factory:[null]" is miss configuration in the ESB_HOME/repository/conf/jndi.properties.

Please recheck it and you can find a really good article on wso2 library - [configuring wso2 esb with wso2 message broker](http://wso2.com/library/articles/2013/03/configuring-wso2-esb-wso2-message-broker/)

Comment: Added jndi.properties file I am using

Answer (score 1):

I have another explanation for this problem. I came across the situation where I deployed my working stuff on a freshly set-up UAT machine. Immediately when the test started I started receiving the "Connection Factory:[null]" problem.
I investigated hours on all configurations and at the end it turned out that I forgot to copy two *jar files into [ESB_HOME]\repository\components\lib

I hope that it helps.